# What is going wrong with the code to display messages from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display the messages received in the firebase database to the desired user.

The text, user1 sends is displayed properly on his device, but not in user2 device even though, the message reaches the firebase database. This is the main problem.

I am using the following code to check for new messages:

```
private void checkMessage(){

        final DatabaseReference rRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference uRef = rRef.child("users");
        final DatabaseReference mRef = uRef.child(toUid);
        final DatabaseReference kRef = mRef.child("rec_msg");

        kRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(toUid)) {
                    Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    assert map != null;
                    String message = map.get("rec_msg").toString();
                    addMessageBox(message, 2);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(toUid)) {
                    Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    assert map != null;
                    String message = map.get("rec_msg").toString();
                    addMessageBox(message, 2);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("Error", databaseError.getDetails());
            }
        });
```

The code that prints the box and shows the text on the screen is like:

```
private void addMessageBox(String message, int type){

            TextView tv = new TextView(Main5Activity.this);
            tv.setText(message);
            tv.setPadding(20, 30, 30, 20);
            tv.setTextSize(1, (float) 20.1);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp2.weight = 1.0f;

            if (type == 1) {
                lp2.gravity = Gravity.END;
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_grey);

            } else {
                lp2.gravity = Gravity.START;
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_violet);
            }

            tv.setLayoutParams(lp2);
            layout.addView(tv);
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

    }
```

The send button code works as following:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String meText = message.getText().toString();


                if (!meText.equals("")) {

                    addMessageBox(meText, 1);
                    storeToUID(toUid, fromUid);
                    sendMessage(message.getText().toString(), toUid);
                    checkMessage();

                }
                message.setText("");

            }
        });
```

The database looks something like this:

[image: database]

The 'sendMessage()' and 'storeToUID()' just store the values on the firebase database.

Also, the 'checkMessage()' when not added inside the send button's listener code, crashes the app.

Where and how should I place the checkMessage() code so that the app works as it should?

Comment: Please share your crash logs, thanks.

Comment: Do you have some message receiver that work on background? It must run your `checkMessage()` automatically when the message added to firebase. Try to use custom object Message for your messages.  On firebase callbacks first of all you need to check `if (dataSnapshot.exists())`

Comment: It crashes the app but with what error? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo it crashes with the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pd.secrettexts/com.pd.secrettexts.Main5Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: @MadhurimaDixit In this case, please add the lines of code at which this error occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo the app crashes when it meets the function 'checkMessage()'. The problem is that the messages reach the firebase database successfully but they are not received on the other user's device.

Comment: @MadhurimaDixit Please add the exact lines of code at which this error occurs, by editing your question.